# How to make a bar graph display variables that take zero as a value?

Tags: python

I'm writing a code that displays how many students earned each grade in a bar graph.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import seaborn as sns
import collections

def input_test_scores():
    #input for number of students
    studentnumber=int(input('Enter number of students'))
    #input for number of tests per student
    numberoftests=int(input('enter number of tests per student'))
    #empty list to store scores
    score=[]
        
    for i in range(studentnumber):
        #empty list for each students name and scores
        studentlist=[]
 
  
                 
                 
                 
        for j in range(numberoftests):
            #input for test score
            print("Enter score for test ", j+1, ":")
            #add students score to their list
            studentlist.append(int(input()))
            #add student list to score list to create a 2d list
         score.append(studentlist)
                 
     
    return score


def summarize_test_scores(score):
     
    A=0
    B=0
    C=0
    D=0
    F=0
    gradelist=[A,B,C,D,F]
    mean=[]
    for data in score:
        m=sum(data)/len(data)
        mean.append(m)
    
    grade=[]
    for x in mean:
        if x >=90:
            grade.append('A')
            A+=1
        
        elif x >=80:
            B+=1
            grade.append('B')
        elif x >=70:
            C+=1
            grade.append('C')
        elif x >=60:
            D+=1
            grade.append('D')
        else:
            F+=1
            grade.append('F')
        

    print("MEAN  GRADE")
    for i in range(len(score)):
        print(f'{mean[i]:.2f}  {grade[i]} ')
    


#rolls = [random.randrange(1, 7) for i in range(600)]
#values, frequencies = np.unique(rolls, return_counts=True)


    #sns.set_style('whitegrid')
    #axes = sns.barplot(x=score, y=grade, palette='bright')


   # axes.set(xlabel='Students', ylabel='Grades') 
    title = f'Student Grades'

    grades_freq = collections.Counter(grade)
    sns.set_style('whitegrid')
   
    axes = sns.barplot(x=list(grades_freq.values()), y=list(grades_freq.keys()), 
palette='bright')
    axes.set(xlabel='Students', ylabel='Grades') 
    axes.set_title(title)



                      

score=input_test_scores ()
summarize_test_scores(score)
```

Right now the code works but only displays the grades that at least one student earned. I need to grade to display Letter grade A-F with how many students earned them, even if no student earned a particular grade
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HniUo.png)